# vector access in "R"

Tags: r, string

everyone. The following is the code. My question is: after typing sentence[3], the output is "plank" ! I thought the output should be 'plank', right ? It is simple, but since i am new to R. Thanks for your time and attention.

```
> sentence <- c('walk', 'the', 'plank')
> sentence[3]
[1] "plank"
```

Comment: The quotes aren't part of the data. Try reading `?Quotes`.

Comment: Type `''` into the console and look at the return value.  `'' == ""` is `TRUE`

Comment: thanks very much, Joran and richard ~

Answer (score 3):

Single and double quotes are equivalent in R.

```
> 'foobar' == "foobar"
[1] TRUE
> identical('foobar', "foobar")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or even just `'' == ""`

Comment: Thanks very much, Gabor~